# How to add new element on JSON file MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express

I have a simple question and I don't know how to formulate it clearly because my english is bad  I will explain with an example:
the MongoDB object is like this :
`{_id:ObjectId("606445724bd1552e94f60691"),email:"exemple@gmail.com",password:"password123"}`

I want to add `age` for example the object will be :

`{_id:ObjectId("606445724bd1552e94f60691"),email:"exemple@gmail.com",password:"password123",age:30}`

just like this please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   { _id: ObjectId("606445724bd1552e94f60691") },
   { $set: { age: 30 } }
)
```

Hopefully you don't store passwords as clear text in your database!

Comment: I'm so grateful friend and don't worry the password is hashed by the bcrypt  package and this is just exemple